# Declare data type to ruamel.yaml so that it can represent/serialize it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am using a function from a python library which returns an object with a specific data type. I would like to serialize that object to a yaml file and I would like to use [ruamel.yaml](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The problem is that `ruamel.yaml` does not know how to serialize the specific data type that the function returns and throws an exception:

```
RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: <...>
```

The question is how to "declare" the data type to `ruamel.yaml` so that it knows how to handle it.

Note: I can't / I don't want to make changes to the library or anything of that sort. I am only the consumer of an API.

To make this more concrete, let's use the following example that uses [`socket.AF_INET`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#constants) which happens to be an [`IntEnum`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b2b023c657ba8c3f4a24d0c847d10fe8e2a73d44/Lib/socket.py#L67-L76) but the specific data type should not be important.

```py
import sys
import socket

import ruamel.yaml

def third_party_lib():
    """ Return a dict with our data """
    return {"AF_INET": socket.AF_INET}

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ="safe", pure=True)
yaml.dump(third_party_lib(), sys.stdout)
```

which gives this error:

```
    ruamel.yaml.YAML.dump(self, data, stream, **kw)
  File "/home/feanor/Prog/git/vps-bench/.direnv/python-venv-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 439, in dump
    return self.dump_all([data], stream, _kw, transform=transform)
  File "/home/feanor/Prog/git/vps-bench/.direnv/python-venv-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 453, in dump_all
    self._context_manager.dump(data)
  File "/home/feanor/Prog/git/vps-bench/.direnv/python-venv-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 801, in dump
    self._yaml.representer.represent(data)
  File "/home/feanor/Prog/git/vps-bench/.direnv/python-venv-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/representer.py", line 84, in represent
    node = self.represent_data(data)
  File "/home/feanor/Prog/git/vps-bench/.direnv/python-venv-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/representer.py", line 111, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_representers[data_types[0]](self, data)
  File "/home/feanor/Prog/git/vps-bench/.direnv/python-venv-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/representer.py", line 359, in represent_dict
    return self.represent_mapping(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data)
  File "/home/feanor/Prog/git/vps-bench/.direnv/python-venv-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/representer.py", line 222, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "/home/feanor/Prog/git/vps-bench/.direnv/python-venv-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/representer.py", line 121, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_representers[None](self, data)
  File "/home/feanor/Prog/git/vps-bench/.direnv/python-venv-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/representer.py", line 392, in represent_undefined
    raise RepresenterError('cannot represent an object: %s' % data)
ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: AddressFamily.AF_INET
```

Comment: You really should have used `syaml.dump(third_party_lib(), sys.stdout)` instead of what you were doing, as documented that is slow and memory-inefficient. Here it just distracts from the real issue: that there is no representer registered ("declared") for `AddressFamily`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order for `ruamel.yaml` to be able to dump a specific class, whether you define it, you get it from the standard library or get if from somewhere else, you need to *register* that class against the representer. (This is not necessary when using `YAML(typ='unsafe')`, but I assume you don't want to resort to that).

This registration can be done in different ways. Assuming you have
done `yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()` or `yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')`, and want to represent `SomeClass`, you can:

- use `yaml.register_class(SomeClass)`. This might work on other classes depending on how they are defined.
- use one of the decorators `@yaml_object(yaml)` or `@yaml.register_class`, just before the `class SomeClass:`
  definition. This is primarily of use when defining your own classes
- add a representer directly using: `yaml.representer.add_representer(SomeClass, some_class_to_yaml)`

The first two ways are just syntactic sugar wrapped around the third way, and they will try to use a method `to_yaml` and a class attribute `yaml_tag` if available, and try to do something sensible if either is not available.

You can try `yaml.register(socket.AF_INET)`, but you'll notice that it fails because:

> AttributeError: 'AddressFamily' object has no attribute '**name**'

So you'll have to resort to the third way using `add_representer()`. The argument `some_class_to_yaml` is a function that will be called when a `SomeClass` instance is encountered, and that function is called with the `yaml.representer` instance as first argument and with the actual data (the instance of `SomeClass`) as second argument.

If `SomeClass` is some container type that could recursively reference itself (indirectly),
you need to take special care dealing with that possibility, but for `socket.AF_INET` this is not necessary.

The specific data type is in so far important, that you need to decide *how* to represent the type in YAML. Quiet often you'll see that that attributes of `SomeClass` are used as keys in a mapping (and then it is the mapping that gets the tag), but sometimes the type can be directly represented in a non-collection type available in YAML such as a string, int, etc., for other classes it makes more sense to be represented as a (tagged) sequence.

When you print `type(socket.AF_INET)`, you'll notice that "SomeClass" is actually `AddressFamily`.
And after inspecting `socket.AF_INET` using `dir()`, you'll notice that there is a `name` attribute and that nicely gives you a string `'AF_INET'`, which can be used to tell the representer how to represent this data as a string, without resorting to some lookup:

```
import sys
import socket
import ruamel.yaml


def repr_socket(representer, data):
    return representer.represent_scalar(u'!socket', data.name)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.representer.add_representer(socket.AddressFamily, repr_socket)

data = dict(sock=socket.AF_INET)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
sock: !socket AF_INET
```

Make sure the tag is defined as unicode (necessary in case you are using Python 2.7).

If you also want to load this, you can extend the `constructor` in a similar way. But this time you'll get a `Node` that you need to convert to `AddressFamily` instance.

```
yaml_str = """\
- !socket AF_INET
- !socket AF_UNIX
"""

def constr_socket(constructor, node):
    return getattr(socket, node.value)

yaml.constructor.add_constructor(u'!socket', constr_socket)
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)

assert data[0] == socket.AF_INET
assert data[1] == socket.AF_UNIX
```

which runs without throwing an exception, and shows that the other
constants in `socket` are handled as well.

Comment: @pmav99 And this probably would not have fitted in a comment under the other question.